# recursive function with for loop: return value issue

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

This recursive xml traversal function that I'm trying to write does visit each node/element/tag correctly and it does pass the base case if statement during testing. What it doesn't do is maintain that correct return node after the function finishes unwrapping. My result is always NULL by the time the main program moves to the next line for some reason. I'm new to recursion so hopefully this is a simple error..

```
TiXmlNode* findNode(TiXmlNode* startNode, const char* searchWord){ 

    if (strcmp(startNode->Value(), searchWord) == 0){// base case
        return startNode;
    }
    else
    {
        for (TiXmlNode* node = startNode->FirstChild(); node; node = node->NextSibling())
        {
            findNode(node, searchWord);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a _final_ `return` and the compiler should have told you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about when the deepest `findNode` call returns `startNode`. Where does it go? Well it was called from here:

```
findNode(node, searchWord);
```

And what are you doing with that result? Nothing! You're ignoring it. You need to `return` it all the way down stack.

Or think about it from the other side. The very first call to `findNode`, if it doesn't go inside the first `if` block, will never reach a `return` statement. It never gets a chance to `return` what you want.

Here's how I'd write it:

```
TiXmlNode* findNode(TiXmlNode* startNode, const char* searchWord){ 

    if (strcmp(startNode->Value(), searchWord) == 0){// base case
        return startNode;
    }

    for (TiXmlNode* node = startNode->FirstChild(); node; node = node->NextSibling())
    {
        TiXmlNode* foundNode = findNode(node, searchWord);
        if (foundNode != NULL) {
            return foundNode;
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Would it just be this: return findNode(node, searchWord);  ?  I think I tried that already..

Comment: @user3806949 Close. The problem then is that the first iteration of the `for` will `return`. You need to only return if you find what you want, and otherwise return `nullptr`.

Comment: That call to findNode() needs to be in there somewhere though. So put a copy of the if statement in the for loop and maybe put findNode() right after the for loop?

Comment: @user3806949 I've added what I think should work to my answer.

Comment: @user3806949 Some notes: the `else` was redundant, so I just got rid of it. I only return a node if it is found by one of the children. If none find it, I return `nullptr`.